# Php email sent with issues on subject chars in Outlook only

Tags: php, character-encoding

Im sending a mail using php, and the subject of the mail has accents.

Im receiving weird characters in Outlook instead the accented chars. If i see the email in a web email client i see the subject perfect.

This is the code that im using to send the email:

```
$to  = 'whateveremail@whatever.com';

$subject = '[WEBSITE] áccent – tésts';

$message = '<p>Test message</p>

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";                                          

$headers.= 'From:equipothermomix@thermomix.com' . "\r\n";                                   

$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message , $headers);
```

How i could solve the issue, do i have to use another charset?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and tried many things which seemed to work at first but always failed in some strange case. In the fin I ended up with pure ascii in subjects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reliable way to send e-mail is using plain 7 bit ASCII so you need to encode strings properly when you want to use anything else. In your case, `[WEBSITE] áccent – tésts` should be encoded as (e.g.) `=?windows-1252?B?W1dFQlNJVEVdIOFjY2VudCCWIHTpc3Rz?=`, where the string splits as:

```
=?windows-1252?B?W1dFQlNJVEVdIOFjY2VudCCWIHTpc3Rz?=
  ^            ^ ^
  |            | |
 Charset       | Data
               |
              Base64
```

Check:

```
echo base64_decode('W1dFQlNJVEVdIOFjY2VudCCWIHTpc3Rz'); // [WEBSITE] áccent – tésts
```

This is just an example of one of the possible ways to encode non-ASCII strings.

When sending e-mail, there are many little details like this that need attention. That's why sooner or later you end up using a proper e-mail package like [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: proper e-mail package like Swift Mailer (v 4.3.0.) fires a wonderful `Notice: iconv() [function.iconv]: Wrong charset, conversion from `windows-1252' to `utf-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE' is not allowed in \lib\classes\Swift\Mime\MimePart.php` when attempting to use `Windows-1252` charset

Comment: @MarcoDemaio - If you think you've found a bug you should [report it](http://swiftmailer.org/bugs). If you think the issue is in your code, please ask your own question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: thanks I solved all my issues using PHPMailer, SwiftMialer is a just piece of junk with a fency looking documentation.

Comment: any ideas when the email address has accented characters?  I have tried using Pear Mailer, and Swift Mailer.  But non seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

If there is a mix of encoding types, special characters are destroyed.

[PHP messing with HTML Charset Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501924/php-messing-with-html-charset-encoding/7502564#7502564)

PHP also has an option for encoding messages.

```
mb_language('uni'); // mail() encoding
```

**PHP - Multibyte String**

- http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: I think it is a problem that, encoding types are mixed together as in "PHP messing with HTML Charset Encoding"

Comment: The subject of an e-mail message has nothing to do with HTML and does not support UTF-8.

Comment: My answers in "PHP messing with HTML Charset Encoding" was not about HTML encoding but to keep track of ecoding against external modules. :)