# PHP & mySQL - ë written as Ã«

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP messing with HTML Charset Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501924/php-messing-with-html-charset-encoding)

We've come across special characters being transformed.

What is causing this? How can we fix it?

For example:

```
ë becomes Ã«
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where is this happening? During PHP parsing or once the data is submitted into the DB?

Comment: Duplicate, asked a lot of times, for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522956/strange-character-in-fresh-wamp-installation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501924/php-messing-with-html-charset-encoding

Comment: Ã« is an actual UTF8 character. While ë is the expected utf8 character. See this usefull link: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats a utf-8 character and you can parse it through utf8_encode() and utf8_decode() in PHP

Answer (score 2):

Charset can be set at numerous places.

- table charset
- field charset
- PHP-MySQL connection charset
- Apache default charset
- and in HTML metainfo

Make sure you use UTF-8 everywhere, and don't forget to setup the connection properly *before* the first query:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting your charset in [HTML document](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset) and with PHP [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)'s function.

Also, you could try to make the first query in MySQL to be `SET NAMES=UTF8` ([SET NAMES utf8 in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql))

Answer (score 0):

If this is the output of a PHP script, I guess you may consider [mb_internal_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) function.

Or you can fix that by HTML encoding meta tag. Like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` inside `<head>...</head>`.

Comment: The charset HTTP header sent by the webserver or by the php script has higher priority than the html meta tag.

Comment: Yet this will be the solution on some browsers