# SQL get all records which contains invalid character for e-diaeresis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some values in table which text contains `A«` instead of `ë`

How to replace those characters with `ë` in SQL ?

I tried with

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Table] 
WHERE [dbo].[Table].CustomValue LIKE '%A«%'
```

How to update those items in query ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE [dbo].[Table].CustomValue LIKE '%A«%'`?

Comment: @Rain336 Ok, awesome, I forgot `LIKE` :) ... How to update those character with correct one ?

Comment: Do you want to *select* corrected text or do you want to *update your table* with corrected text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP & mySQL - ë written as Ã«](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609509/php-mysql-%c3%ab-written-as-%c3%83)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to `SELECT` the data then

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(CustomValue, 'A«', N'ë')
FROM [dbo].[Table] 
WHERE [dbo].[Table].CustomValue LIKE '%A«%'
```

If you really needs to `UPDATE` the data then

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table]
SET CustomValue = REPLACE(CustomValue, 'A«', N'ë')
WHERE [dbo].[Table].CustomValue LIKE '%A«%'
```

Answer (score 0):

An `UPDATE` statment with the `REPLACE` function should do the trick.

```sql
UPDATE [dbo].[Table]
SET CustomValue = REPLACE(CustomValue, 'A«', 'ë')
WHERE CustomValue LIKE '%A«%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking just for

```
update dbo.table 
set customvalue = replace(customvalue, 'A«', 'ë')
where customvalue like '%A«%';
```

But maybe your collation does not allow the character 'ë'. In that case you'd have to change the column definition first. E.g.

```
alter table dbo.table
  alter column customvalue nvarchar(1000) collate latin1_general_cs_as;
```